# Automated, configurable, content display software

Tags: display, cms

We are working on a project to install monitors within our various delivery teams' work areas.  We are going to use these monitors to display content from various sources, metrics, announcements, iteration status, build status, things like that.

Normally a presentation like this would just be put in PowerPoint and set to loop, but that doesn't work for a few reasons.  We want to display multiple content items simultaneously and we want to be able to pull from live data sources so that the display is of real-time data.

Here are the must haves:

- Frames:  I would like to be able to put multiple content items on the screen simultaneously. So picture two frames (that's an unintended pun), the left half of the screen could have iteration status, while the right half of the screen could have the release schedule, and for kicks lets say there is a stock ticker style banner running underneath with the build status and version.
- Configurable timing:  Content A is easy to digest. I only need it on screen for 5 seconds, Content B is more complicated I want it up for 20 seconds.  Each item displayed should be configurable.
- Pull data in through various API's, other websites (internal network) and from shared network storage files.
- Windows
- Scripting for set up is acceptable (JS, Perl, Python etc) but should be minimal for maintenance.